# Understanding ESRI's .asc file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, file-formats, ascii, esri-ascii-raster

Reading the ArcGIS help: [Supported raster dataset file formats](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Supported_raster_dataset_file_formats/009t0000000q000000/GUID-86B6BD7A-029A-43AB-9686-FD25BDE4048F/), I read that ASCII Grid file types are addressed with the singular file extension `.asc` for both 16 bit signed-integer (for discrete data) and 32 bit floating-point files (for continuous data).

They say in [ESRI Grid format](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Esri_Grid_format/009t0000000w000000/) section:

> A grid is a raster data storage format native to ESRI. There are two types of grids: integer and floating point.

and then, it describes what both formats are.

My confusion comes in the next help section [ESRI ASCII raster format](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Esri_ASCII_raster_format/009t0000000z000000/). There, they only mention the floating point format. So, I would like to know:

1. Is the 16-bit signed integer format for discrete data also considered a raster format, besides grid?
2. In 'ESRI Grid format - Grid data storage' section, they cite several other extensions such as `.bnd`, `.hrd`, etc.? Is the 16-bit signed-integer `.asc`-file, the ASCII version of an Esri discrete data grid format?

The motivation for this question is to describe/understand what is a file with extension `.asc`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the Esri world an `.asc` file *usually* refers to the output created by the [GRIDASCII](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=gridascii) command (ArcInfo Workstation) or [Raster to ASCII](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000005000000) tool (ArcGIS for Desktop). In practice it can mean just about any format, usually plain text, meaning one can't assume from the `.asc` extension what it looks like inside.

It's an interchange format, meaning it's not (normally) used as input for analysis or primary storage, but for exchange with other programs.

The Esri ASCII Raster format can use either integer or floating point numbers for the Z (cell) value. These are both valid:

```
NCOLS 480
NROWS 450
XLLCORNER 378922
YLLCORNER 4072345
CELLSIZE 30
NODATA_VALUE -9999
43 2 45 7 3 56 2 5 23 65 34 6 32 54 57 34
35 45 65 34 2 6 78 4 2 6 89 3 2 7 45 23 5 ...

NCOLS 480
NROWS 450
XLLCORNER 378922
YLLCORNER 4072345
CELLSIZE 30
NODATA_VALUE -32768
43.245 7.356 2.523 6.534 6.325 57.34
35.456 34.267 4.268 32.745 23.5 ...
```

The **Esri GRID format**, also called Arcinfo Binary Grid, is comprised of multiple files in a single directory (`.hdr`,`.adf`,...) and whose contents are opaque (looks like gobbledygook in a text editor). The grid specification is unpublished, but has been very [successfully reverse engineered](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/arcinfo_grid_format.html#raster-arcinfo-grid-format). Binary Grid is the default raster format for ArcInfo Workstation (actually comes from its GRID program) and is used as primary storage and analysis input.

You didn't ask about this, but for completeness: there is also the **Esri floating point grid** interchange file format. It is not used for primary storage or analysis.

Floating point grids are created from the [GRIDFLOAT](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=gridfloat) (ArcInfo Workstation) command or [Raster to Float](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000006000000) (ArcGIS for Desktop) tool and *typically* has a `.flt` extension for the raw values (binary encoded), and side car `.hdr` file describing the format. The .hdr is plain text and resembles the beginning of an .asc file:

```
ncols         382
nrows         425
xllcorner     217996.296875
yllcorner     708952.625
cellsize      300.0741885626
NODATA_value  -9999
byteorder     LSBFIRST
```

---

**In practice**, if you have a file of unknown format that you think might be a raster, show it to [gdalinfo](http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html) from [gdal](/questions/tagged/gdal) and it will usually be able to uncover what it is:

```
D:\> gdalinfo strange_file.raw

Driver: AAIGrid/Arc/Info ASCII Grid
Files: strange_file.raw
Size is 382, 425
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (217996.296875000000000,836484.155139103760000)
Pixel Size = (300.074188562596990,-300.074188562596990)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  217996.297,  836484.155)
Lower Left  (  217996.297,  708952.625)
Upper Right (  332624.637,  836484.155)
Lower Right (  332624.637,  708952.625)
Center      (  275310.467,  772718.390)
Band 1 Block=382x1 Type=Int32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-2147483648
```

.

```
D:\>gdalinfo strange_file_too.raw

Driver: EHdr/ESRI .hdr Labelled
Files: strange_file_too.flt
       strange_file_too.hdr
       strange_file_too.prj
Size is 382, 425
  ...snip...
Band 1 Block=382x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-9999
```

*...and then use [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) to convert it something useful if you don't have ArcGIS for Desktop handy.*

Comment: ...for completeness I also added something about GRIDFLOAT

Answer (score 3):

Esri grid formats are proprietary binary files.  There is no such thing as an ASCII version of grid files.  There is an ASCII transfer format, which your post references.

I've never tried loading floating-point data in an ASCII file, but I know that 16-bit signed data would be accepted (integer grids are 32-bit signed data). The ASCII data is converted to a grid on import, which could then be exported to any one of a dozen different  16-bit binary formats.

Note that the ".asc" extension is not required, or exclusive, so it's confusing to make references to "extension .asc".

Comment: *Any* file can be a binary, including anything with a ".txt" suffix.
Frankly, if you need to write the file anyway, it makes better sense to create a .bsq/.bil/.bip file, with a .hdr that conforms to http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t00000010000000 -- the resulting binary file will be a fraction of the size of the .asc and more directly usable.