# Open LiDAR DEM of the UK with *.asc extension

Tags: gdal, dem, lidar, envi, esri-ascii-raster

I've downloaded a tile of a freely accessible `LiDAR DEM` of the `UK` from http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/survey#/download.

But I don't know how to open it. The files inside have the `*.asc` extension.
I can see that this extension is not among those supported by `Gdal`. And, neither Sentinel Application Platform `SNAP` nor `ENVI` did manage to open it.

Which software is used to open these `DEM` files?

Comment: asc usually means ascii

Comment: potentially the Environment Agency will be releasing raw .las files which will have even more potential. Wales also has Lidar as Opendata now http://lle.gov.wales/GridProducts#data=LidarCompositeDataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are ESRI ASCII grid files:

```
$ head -6 sd5755_DSM_2m.asc 
ncols        500
nrows        500
xllcorner    357000
yllcorner    455000
cellsize     2
NODATA_value  -9999
```

with coordinates in OSGB grid references (EPSG code 27700). This is about the only thing GDAL doesn't know about them:

```
$ gdalinfo sd5755_DSM_2m.asc 
Driver: AAIGrid/Arc/Info ASCII Grid
Files: sd5755_DSM_2m.asc
Size is 500, 500
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (357000.000000000000000,456000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (2.000000000000000,-2.000000000000000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  357000.000,  456000.000) 
Lower Left  (  357000.000,  455000.000) 
Upper Right (  358000.000,  456000.000) 
Lower Right (  358000.000,  455000.000) 
Center      (  357500.000,  455500.000) 
Band 1 Block=500x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-9999
```

so you'll have to tell your GIS about the CRS if you need to project it to anything else.

Comment: Do you know why there are `41 files` for `1m` resolution `DTM` and `DSM`?

Comment: Because the UK is quite big

Comment: with most of the gdal commands you can add projection with -s_srs epsg:27700 (OSGB Grid)

Answer (score 3):

GDAL can open this for you, it should be a [ASCII file](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html). You can easily translate to tif with

`gdal_translate source.asc dest.tif`

Comment: Does it mean that it's a vector?

Comment: [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71867/understanding-the-asc-file) might give you some more insight.

Comment: The elevation seems to be given in `meters`

Comment: ASC (*.asc) files are rasters and will load into QGIS using the "Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Raster Layer..." dialogue.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a two step approach to create a single file from all the downloaded ASCII format files using two GDAL utilities. From within the unzipped file:

1. Create a 'Virtual Raster' with all the files:

   gdalbuildvrt merged_mosaic.vrt *asc

I'm not sure how the shell expansion will work if you are using windows - you could also pass in a list of files, see http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html for more details.

2. Convert the VRT to a GeoTIFF (or any other format GDAL supports) and assign the OSGB projection:

   gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:27700 merged_mosaic.vrt merged_mosaic.tif

If it is of any use I also wrote a script which will mosaic the files from within the zip file. It uses RSGISLib (http://rsgislib.org/) but could be adapted to use gdalbuildvrt / gdal_translate instead. See: https://spectraldifferences.wordpress.com/2015/09/02/mosaic-environment-agency-dtmdsm-tiles-using-rsgislib/ for details.

Update: I have also written a script which will mosaic tiles using GRASS: https://gist.github.com/arsf/fcf51a0dd8b7dcde8243